# How to resolve 'Element type is invalid' error when testing a React component using @mui/icons-material?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm facing an issue that I can't figure out how to resolve.
i'm trying to test this component:

```js
import LabelIconButton from '../LabelIconButton'
import { PowerSettingsNew } from '@mui/icons-material'

export default function LabelIconButtonDisconnection() {
  return <LabelIconButton title="déconnexion" icon={PowerSettingsNew} />
}
```

With this test:

```js
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import LabelIconButton from '../LabelIconButton'
import { PowerSettingsNew } from '@mui/icons-material'
import LabelIconButtonDisconnection from './LabelIconButtonDisconnection'

jest.mock('../LabelIconButton', () => {
  return jest.fn(() => <div>Mock LabelIconButton</div>)
})

describe('LabelIconButtonDisconnection', () => {
  it('appelle le composant LabelIconButton avec les bonnes props', () => {
    render(<LabelIconButtonDisconnection/>)

    expect(LabelIconButton).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      title: 'déconnexion',
      icon: PowerSettingsNew,
    }, {})
  })
})
```

I have this message error on the render of my test:

```
 Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
```

The issue is that no matter how much I check my imports (which seem correct to me), nothing works. It might be due to the icons-material. I've tried mocking it, but it doesn't work.

Could you help me pls ?

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is possibly being caused by how LabelIconButton in the test is being mocked. Since LabelIconButton is a default export, you can try using default export when mocking it.

```
jest.mock('../LabelIconButton', () => {
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: jest.fn(() => <div>Mock LabelIconButton</div>),
  }
})
```

using the __esModule: true and default: jest.fn() hopefully will ensure that the LabelIconButton import gets recognised by test.

Answer (score 0):

Can you re-check your default imports vs non-default? We only see a very small part of the code, so it's hard to be sure.

For example, I'm able to reproduce the error by doing this

`import { LabelIconButtonDisconnection } from '../LabelIconButtonDisconnection'`

when it should be

`import LabelIconButtonDisconnection from '../LabelIconButtonDisconnection'` because it's a default export.